# What is the nature of Triangle if AB/AC=1/2 angle (BAC)=60°

Tags: geometry, triangles

What is the nature of  Triangle if $\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac12$ and $\angle BAC=60^{\circ}$?. Can we use ratio between side lengths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using common notation, $BC=a,CA=b,AB=c$

We have $\displaystyle\frac cb=\frac12\iff b=2c\  \ \ \ (1) $

Applying [cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) $$\cos\angle BAC=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$

Using $(1)$
$$\frac{(2c)^2+c^2-a^2}{2(2c)c}=\cos60^\circ=\frac12\implies a^2=\cdots$$

Comment: Can we use ratio between side lengths?

Comment: @user146386, That's what we have done here

Comment: Can we say if AB/AC=cos (angle (BAC)) then  triangle is rectangle???

Comment: @pr_ahmedkh What is the cosine of angle BAC if the angle is 60°?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: apply the *law of cosines*, and you get: $$BC^2=AB^2+AC^2-2AB\cdot AC \cos\angle BAC\\=AB^2+4AB^2-2AB\cdot2AB\frac12=AB^2+4AB^2-2AB^2=3AB^2\Rightarrow \\BC=AB\sqrt{3} \qquad AC=2AB$$
we must conclude that $\Delta ABC$ is a $30°-60°$ rectangular triangle with the hypothenuse coincident with $AC$.

Comment: Can we say if AB/AC=cos (angle (BAC)) then triangle is rectangle???

Comment: YES! of course! because if the triangle was rectangle you could say $$AB=AC\cos(\angle BAC) \Rightarrow \frac{AB}{AC}=\cos(\angle BAC)$$!